# JAVA: If I have a class that contains an array, how would I access that array in my main method?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am making my first game in java, and I would like to keep things organized, but I am having trouble figuring out how to access my array for use in my main method, which will run the game.

This is my code for the array.

```
package game;

public class Monsters {

    public static void createMonsterList(String[] args) {

        monsterTemplate[] monsterList = new monsterTemplate[9];
        {
            monsterList[0] = new monsterTemplate("Ghoul", 10, 40, 15);
            monsterList[1] = new monsterTemplate("Gremlin", 7, 15, 5);
            monsterList[2] = new monsterTemplate("Grue", 15, 100, 30);
            monsterList[3] = new monsterTemplate("Py", 10, 20, 10);
            monsterList[4] = new monsterTemplate("Skeleton", 8, 25, 8);
            monsterList[5] = new monsterTemplate("Zombie", 5, 40, 10);
            monsterList[6] = new monsterTemplate("Goblin", 5, 10, 2);
            monsterList[7] = new monsterTemplate("Troll", 20, 250, 50);
            monsterList[8] = new monsterTemplate("Slime", 4, 10, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I have no idea how to use it after I have made this class file. I want to be able to just get one of the monsters and use the data I have within the array. I do have getters in the monsterTemplate class.

If there is anymore information anyone needs to help me, I can supply it.

Comment: Your array is only in scope in your static method.

Comment: `monsterList` is a variable, so it is discarded when the method returns. In this particular case, you should remove `args` parameter and you should return the list.

Comment: I recommend a basic Java tutorial. You have an unnecessary parameter to the method, your array is a local variable and it's initialized in a weird way (but by pure chance it's not incorrect syntax and actually does what you're hoping it does).

Answer (score 0):

The instance variables of your class are not created in a static method, you can instead declare these before your constructor which will always be called when a new instance of your Monsters object is created (in this case the method public Monsters is your constructor).

If you did something like what I have below you can see that when you create a new Monster object you will now be able to access (and modify) your array.

```
package game;

public class Monsters {

   private monsterTemplate[] monsterList = new monsterTemplate[9];

   public Monsters(){
       initMonsters();
   }

   private void initMonsters(){
      monsterList[0] = new monsterTemplate("Ghoul", 10, 40, 15);
      monsterList[1] = new monsterTemplate("Gremlin", 7, 15, 5);
      monsterList[2] = new monsterTemplate("Grue", 15, 100, 30);
      monsterList[3] = new monsterTemplate("Py", 10, 20, 10);
      monsterList[4] = new monsterTemplate("Skeleton", 8, 25, 8);
      monsterList[5] = new monsterTemplate("Zombie", 5, 40, 10);
      monsterList[6] = new monsterTemplate("Goblin", 5, 10, 2);
      monsterList[7] = new monsterTemplate("Troll", 20, 250, 50);
      monsterList[8] = new monsterTemplate("Slime", 4, 10, 1);
   }

   public monsterTemplate[] getMonsters(){
       return monsterList;
   }

   // An example of how this class would be used.
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Monsters monsters = new Monsters();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`monsterList` is a local variable of `createMonsterList`. To access it from other methods in `Monsters` you should extract it as class field.

There is a good post about variables [life-cycle and scopes](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html). I recommend to read it.

Short examples:

```
class A {
    public void method() {
        // int b = a; <- illegal before a is defined
        // a is visible only within this method after declaration
        int a;
    }
    // a is not defined here
 }

class B {
    // b is a class field you can access b from any instance of B
    public int b;

    public int method() {
        return b;
    }
}
new B().b // <- access b in instance

class C {
    // c is a static field it is accessible even without class instance
    static int c;
    static int getC() {
        return c;
    }

    int getCNonStatic() {
        return c;
    }
}
C.c  // <- access field by class name
```

Comment: Am not sure this guy would understand your answer. he needs basic explaination...far far basic. Thus, considering the kind of code he is writing.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables can only be accessed by static functions. So you could make your functions `static` and then access the variable after turning it into an instance variable; it's local in your example.

Java developers don't usually write much code into a `Main` method except for the simplest of applications.

Take a look into SpringBoot which will help you write a well structured application. Then you can inject your arrays via an `@Value` variable or set using an `@Autowired` method. SB will set you on the path to creating the next great web application.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, since you're using an array, it looks like your set of Monsters is fixed. When creating a fixed set, I would prefer to use an [enum api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/security/Provider.html) like this:

```
public enum Monster {

      GHOUL("Ghoul", 10, 40, 15),
      GREMLIN("Gremlin", 7, 15, 5);
      GRUE("Grue", 15, 100, 30);
      PY("Py", 10, 20, 10);
      SKELETON("Skeleton", 8, 25, 8);
      ZOMBIE("Zombie", 5, 40, 10);
      GOBLIN("Goblin", 5, 10, 2);
      TROLL("Troll", 20, 250, 50);
      SLIME("Slime", 4, 10, 1);

   private String name;

   private int a;
   private int b;
   private int c;

   private Monster(String name, int a, int b, int c){
       this.name = name;
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = c;
   }

}

public class MyMainClass {

   public static void main() {

       Monster currentMonster = Monster.GOBLIN;
       Monster[] monsters = Monster.values();
   }
}
```

However you probably want to create monsters on the fly, I would prefer a List or Map, instead of an array, since you can dynamically add more monsters to your list when needed.

```
public class Monster {

       private String name;

       private int a;
       private int b;
       private int c;

       public Monster(String name, int a, int b, int c){
           this.name = name;
           this.a = a;
           this.b = b;
           this.c = c;
       }
}



public class MyMainClass {

       private Map<String,Monster> monsters = new HashMap<>();

       private Monster ghoul = new Monster("Ghoul", 10, 40, 15);
       private Monster gremlin = new Monster("Gremlin", 7, 15, 5)
       private Monster grue = new Monster("Grue", 15, 100, 30);
       private Monster py = new Monster("Py", 10, 20, 10);
       private Monster skeleton = new Monster("Skeleton", 8, 25, 8);
       private Monster zombie = new Monster("Zombie", 5, 40, 10);
       private Monster goblin = new Monster("Goblin", 5, 10, 2);
       private Monster troll = new Monster("Troll", 20, 250, 50);
       private Monster slime = new Monster("Slime", 4, 10, 1);

       public void init() {

              monsters.put(ghoul.getName(), ghoul);
              monsters.put(gremlin.getName(), gremlin);
              monsters.put(grue.getName(), grue);
              monsters.put(py.getName(), py);
              monsters.put(skeleton.getName(), skeleton);
              monsters.put(zombie.getName(), zombie);
              monsters.put(goblin.getName(), goblin);
              monsters.put(troll.getName(), troll);
              monsters.put(slime.getName(), slime);
        }

        public static void main() {

              init();
              Monster currentMonster = monsters.get("Ghoul");
              Collection<Monster> monsters = monsters.values();
              monsters.put("New monster", new Monster("New monster",1,2,3));
        }
}
```

You seem to have little java experience, I would recommend to do some tutorial first. Next to that java has some coding standards like camelcasing etc. which is very useful to learn and will make your code more readable.

Comment: Since it's a game, it's better to keep it in a format that is easily expandable and modifiable without needing a recompile, and this outside a programming environment. That's usually done with files that have a format friendly to, or specifically designed for, data-objects and attribute-value pairs, such as XML or JSON. --- Although your answer is valid regarding the fixed-sets in general programming, it isn't regarding games or other software where the set is expected to be changed between releases (balancing/expansion) or by the users (customization/modding).